# Unknown column 'P_KEY' in 'where clause' UPDATE but 'SELECT' works

Tags: mysql

i tried to execute

```
UPDATE lineitem
SET lineitem.L_TAX = 1
WHERE L_ORDERKEY =4996;
```

" but it don't work

> Unknown column 'L_ORDERKEY' in 'where clause'

[image]

here is the table desc

[image]

if i execute `SELECT * FROM lineitem WHERE L_ORDERKEY = 4996;` it works

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/_W-kbCKc

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, i create a wrong trigger and the error message is actually come from the trigger. (the error message really get me confused...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).